# How to access apache website via domain name?

Tags: linux

I have set up an apache server and I want to be able to access the website from any device that connects to the local network via http:// (eg. http://server1-website or http://127.0.0.1) instead of using the server’s ip address.
Is there a way to do this without editting the hosts file?

Comment: If you have never heard of a DNS Server, you ahve no business being here and should be on superuser.om - and DNS Server is the answer to the question ("is there any way to do that instead of the hosts file").

Comment: This answer explains both DNS basics and the Apache settings for host name: https://serverfault.com/questions/520195/how-does-servername-and-serveralias-work